# Hibernate 5 Association [] references an unmapped entity [] : origin(User.hbm.xml)

Tags: java, hibernate, hbmxml

I'm STILL dealing with a non-Spring legacy application, with a matching legacy database that is not easily updateable, so I have to deal with the cards that were dealt me.

I'm moving this non-Spring app from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 5 and I was running into some issues so let me say they have a primary-hibernate.cfg.xml with these three classes, in this order:

```
<mapping class="com.app.server.model.user.UserRolePK" /> 
<mapping class="com.app.server.model.user.UserRole" />

<mapping resource="com/app/server/model/user/User.hbm.xml"/>
```

The first classes is defined as follows:

```
public class UserRolePK implements Serializable {
    @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "elt",  insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    // getters/setters/equals/hashcode/toString
}
```

The main class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
@IdClass(UserRolePK.class)
public class UserRole implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId",  referencedColumnName = "id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private User user;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "elt",  insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    // getters/setters/equals/hashcode/toString
}
```

I can tell you I created a Dao Class for the UserRole with UserRolePK and they work 100%.  I can access the database and get all the records from the table 'roles' with no problem.  So, I know this part works.

Finally the User.hbm.xml looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="com.app.server.model.user">
    <class name="User" table="user">
         <id name="id" column="id">
              <generator class="native" />
        </id>
  
     <bag name="roles" cascade = "all,delete-orphan" lazy="false">
          <key column="userId" not-null="true"/>
          <one-to-many class="com.app.server.model.user.UserRole"/>
     </bag>

     // more properties not relevant at this time

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I thought this was all good, but I am getting an error when I run the application.  I get this nasty error:

```
org.hibernate.boot.MappingException: Association [com.app.server.model.user.User.roles] references an unmapped entity [com.app.server.model.user.User.roles] : origin(com/app/server/model/user/User.hbm.xml)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder$AbstractPluralAttributeSecondPass.bindCollectionTable(ModelBinder.java:3195)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.hbm.ModelBinder$AbstractPluralAttributeSecondPass.doSecondPass(ModelBinder.java:3133) ... 
more error messages
```

Now I am experimenting with the 'roles' in a variety of ways, add a table:

```
<bag name="roles" table="roles" cascade = "all,delete-orphan" lazy="false">
    <key column="userId" not-null="true"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.app.server.model.user.UserRole"/>
</bag>
```

Or, change from bag to set:

```
<set name="roles" table="roles" cascade = "all,delete-orphan" lazy="false">
    <key column="userId" not-null="true"/>
    <one-to-many class="com.app.server.model.user.UserRole"/>
</set>
```

But this doesn't work. I would love to turn all the hbm.xml files into annotated tables, but the legacy app I am working on already has a class defined:  com.app.server.model.user.User
and unfortunately, they decided to stick a bunch of business logic into a hibernate entity.  This business logic changes the values of things, and I wouldn't do that here, so I may have to change it to someplace else.

Hopefully, this is an easy fix within the User.hbm.xml file and it will make my error go away.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this issue is due to hbm.xml being considered as "complete" so it's imported and validate first I think. Try getting rid of the hbm.xml and this should go away.